# Android support library not found

Tags: android, windows, gradle

I am using the Facebook SDK for an Android project and I am having issues compiling the support-v4 library into my project. The error I am getting is: `Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0`

I have installed the Android Support Repository using the SDK.

The thing that hangs me up is that it looks like gradle does not try to look using the local maven repository. When I run `gradlew.bat assembleDebug --debug` on a working machine, I get:

```
19:01:23.803 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting configuration <PROJECT>.facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1:facebook:unspecified(_debugCompile). 669
19:01:23.803 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting dependency <PROJECT>.facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1:facebook:unspecified(_debugCompile) -> com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+(dependency: com.android.support#support-v4;13.0.+ {compile=[default]})
19:01:23.804 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver] Attempting to resolve module 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+' using repositories [BintrayJCenter, maven, maven2]
```

while on the non-working machine, I get:

```
...
23:27:41.642 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver] Attempting to resolve module 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0' using repositories [BintrayJCenter]
```

Other relevant pieces of info:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk

Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\;C:\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\wbin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\PSTools;C:\apache-maven-3.0.3-bin\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\Program;C:\NUnit-2.6.3\NUnit-2.6.3\bin\
```

Comment: There's an item called 'Google Repository' under Extras. It is said to resolve such problems, when installed - can you check?

Comment: Everything under the extras section, including the Android Support Repository and the Google Repository, is installed.

Comment: What I noticed was that it seems to be looking for different versions 20.0.0 vs 13.0.+ - are you trying to run two different version of the project?
The repos are driven from the outer build.gradle file (not the one under app/, but the one in the project root). What I have there is

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

 - what do you have there on your two machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the ANDROID_HOME path was incorrect. I thought that it was:

`ANDROID_HOME=C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk`

but in reality it was:

`ANDROID_HOME=C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools`

Once I closed out the current command prompt and opened up a fresh prompt, it worked fine.